# Add/Update translatation locale in module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to update translatation locale in **Module.php**?
I have tried this:

```
$locale = 'de_DE';//will be generated dynamically
$translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');         
$translator->setLocale($locale)->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
```

In module.config.php, the code is:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),

'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

I have tried commenting the translation file path but stil it shows en_US text. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it's because fallback locale is used.  Are you sure, you have that text translated to `de_DE` locale?

Comment: yup 100% sure. Also I have checked the fallback locale. It is going for setLocale only.

Comment: is the path the correct one? (if your module is in /modules/YOURMODULE/Module.php, you are pointing to /modules/language). If it is correct, and the file name is ok (de_DE.mo) then the code seems to be perfect. It could be that you are not using it in the correct place. where do you have that code? in the bootstrap? probably if you do it after dispatch, and before render, it will work. I just say since i use to do it in the dispatch event.

Comment: the path is correct. I have this code in onBootstrap function.
Also "after dispatch, and before render" Can you explain it a little more.

Comment: i write an answer, so i can include some code

Answer (score 0):

To change the locale after the action is dispathed, but before the view is rendered, you attach a function to the dispatch event. In you bootstrap you can do:

```
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

    $sm = $e->getApplication ()->getServiceManager ();

    $em = $e->getApplication ()->getEventManager ();

     $em->attach ( MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function ($e) use($sm) {


                 $locale = 'de_DE';//will be generated dynamically
                 $translator = $sm->get('translator');         
                 $translator->setLocale($locale)->setFallbackLocale('en_US');



             }, - 100 );


     }
```